# Как сделать выборку из массива по длине строк и отсортировать ее по алфавиту

Tags: c#, linq

Дано целое число L (> 0) и последовательность непустых строк A. Строки
последовательности содержат только цифры и заглавные буквы латинского алфавита. Из
элементов A, предшествующих первому элементу, длина которого превышает L, извлечь
строки, оканчивающиеся буквой. Полученную последовательность отсортировать по
убыванию длин строк, а строки одинаковой длины — в лексикографическом порядке по
возрастанию.

```
string[] A =
{
    "I1989IGOR", "IGOR1989", "P1989PETRO", "PETRO1989", "S1989SERGEY", "SERGEY1989",
    "A1989ANNA","ANNA1989", "TERAB1989", "T1989TERAB"
};

int L = 5;

var query1 = A.Where(item => item.Length > L && Char.IsUpper(item, item.Length - 1))
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Length);

var query2 = from item in query1
             group item by item.Length into gl
             where gl.Count() > 1
             select gl.Key;

var query3 = from item1 in query1
             from item2 in query2
             where item1.Length == item2
             orderby item1
             select item1;

Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 50));
Console.WriteLine("Show all the arr: \n");
Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 50));
foreach (var item in A)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 50));
Console.WriteLine("Show query one: \n");
Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 50));
foreach (var item in query1)
{
    Console.Write(item + "\n");
}
Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 50));
Console.WriteLine("Show query two: \n");
Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 50));
foreach (var item in query2)
{
    Console.Write(item + "\n");
}
Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 50));
Console.WriteLine("Show query three: \n");
Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 50));
foreach (var item in query3)
{
    Console.Write(item + "\n");
}
Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 50));
```

Comment: Мой код очень длинный хочется лаконично и красиво!

Comment: что-то приведенный код никак не связан с описанным заданием

Comment: Обязательно LINQ? А то это выглядит как забивание гвоздя микроскопом)

Comment: Да все верно я задание не понял уже разобрался спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var A = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>()
{
    "BF","C", "BA", "A", "IFD4", "I1989IGOR", "AGOR1989", "P1989PETRO", "PETRO1989", "S1989SERGEY", "SERGEY1989",
        "A1989ANNA","ANNA1989", "TERAB1989", "T1989TERAB"
};

int L = 10;

var resultList = A.TakeWhile(x => x.Length <= L)
    .Where(str => Char.IsLetter(str.Last()))
    .OrderByDescending(str => str.Length)
    .ThenBy(str => str)
    .ToList();

foreach (var x in resultList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Вывод

```
P1989PETRO
I1989IGOR
BA
BF
A
C
```

Верно?

Comment: Там еще условие об окончании на букву .Where(x => Char.IsLetter(x.ElementAt(x.Length - 1))) перед сортировкой

Comment: @OleksiiPotapov Точно, поправил)

Comment: [TakeWhile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Grundy О, да, так круче)

Answer (score 2):

Задача выборки практически однозначно ложится на функции linq

1. *Из элементов A, предшествующих первому элементу, длина которого превышает L* - брать элементы пока длина не превышает `L` - [`TakeWhile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=netframework-4.8)
2. *извлечь строки, оканчивающиеся буквой.* - отфильтровать элементы удовлетворяющие условию - [`Where`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8)
3. *Полученную последовательность отсортировать по убыванию длин строк* - сортировка по убыванию - [`OrderByDescending`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netframework-4.8)
4. *строки одинаковой длины — в лексикографическом порядке* - сортировка по возрастанию - [`ThenBy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=netframework-4.8)

---

Итоговое выражение может быть следующим:

```
A.TakeWhile(a=>a.Length<=L)
 .Where(a=>Char.IsLetter(a.Last()))
 .OrderByDescending(a=>a.Length)
 .ThenBy(a=>a);
```

---